# How to have the same variables as both SCSS variables and CSS custom properties?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I'm refactoring a code base using SCSS variables to use CSS custom properties instead. For backwards compatibility I'd like to keep all the variables in SCSS as well, without having to repeat them. Is there a way to achieve that?

Basically what I'd want to achieve is this

```
$variables: (
  foo: 10px,
  bar: red,
  baz: "foo",
);

// This should be the result without repeating foo, bar & baz
$foo: 10px;
$bar: red;
$baz: "foo";

:root {
  --foo: 10px;
  --bar: red;
  --baz: "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not entirely possible as an automated process.
The issue is that a `$var` can not be declared from within a map. You need to explicitly declare each `$var` yourself.

Thus the only way to come close to your desired outcome would be to create a separate map, iterating over it to generate CSS custom properties and still having to declare each `$var` per hand.

```
$foo: foo;
$bar: bar;
$faz: faz;

//

$vars: (
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar,
  faz: faz,
);

:root {
  @each $key, $value in $vars {
    --#{$key}: $var;
  }
}
```